# Command line compiling an iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, xcode, build-process, continuous-integration, build-automation

I would like to find a way to compile and package our iPhone application as part of our automated nightly build.  At present we always have to manually kick off a build on a shared Mac that has the adhoc certificates installed on the box and then post the resulting test binaries some place where testers can pull them down and install them.

Has anyone found an approach to automation that works for them?

Comment: Another solution (maybe a bit more detailed):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line Have a look at my answer there. It especially deals with integrating the CLI build into a CI for OTA distribution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a command line tool to build Xcode projects: `xcodebuild`

Answer (score 3):

Try using xcodebuild, it'll build an Xcode project from the command line.  You can then pull the binaries out of the build directory.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an [XCodeBuilder](http://blog.jeffreyfredrick.com/2008/11/27/continuous-integration-for-iphonexcode-projects/) (it calls xcodebuild) for [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) that is now part of the standard release. We used this on an app that is now in the app store and it was great. After every commit a version of the app w/the ad-hoc signature was ready for download and testing by the rest of the team.