# Did someone port uw imap c-client to iPhone OS (device)?

Tags: iphone, ios, gcc, imap

I downloaded the source code, typed 'make oxp' then I got a file named 'c-client.a', I think it is for X86.

But how can I build this library for iPhone OS (device)?

Answer (score 0):

For command-line compilation for iPhone, you can look at:

- http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-compile-command-line-utility-for.html
- [Command line compiling an iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358939)