# creating ipa file using command line with code signing

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am trying to create an ipa file using xcode command line including signing.
i tried searching for it, i got the commands to create ipa with out code signing.

i need the commands mainly to integrate with hudson CI.

Please suggest.

-Prahasa

Answer (score 6):

This is the script which I use to integrate with Hudson and my iPhone Apps.

```
#!/bin/sh

CONFIGURATION="AdHoc" # or Release or Debug

# location of files included in dist (.mobileprovision, iTunesArtwork, README)
DISTDIR="_distfiles"

. build.config

MARKETING_VERSION=`agvtool what-marketing-version -terse1`

build_xcode ()
    {
    xcodebuild -configuration "$CONFIGURATION" -sdk $SDK
}

# CONFIGURATION for xcode build can be overridden from commandline
NEWCONFIG="$1"
if ! test "$NEWCONFIG"x = x; then
    echo "=== using configuration from command line $NEWCONFIG"
    CONFIGURATION="$NEWCONFIG"
fi

# XCODE check build available for specified configuration
CHECKCONFIGURATION=`xcodebuild -list | egrep "$CONFIGURATION($|\ )"`
if test "$CHECKCONFIGURATION"x = x; then
    echo "ERROR: xcodebuild could not find valid build configuration $CONFIGURATION"
    echo
    xcodebuild -list
    echo
    exit
fi

VERSION="$MARKETING_VERSION ($BUILD_NUMBER)"
#######
echo "=== Building distribution package for $RELEASE - $VERSION"
echo "=== setting build number to $BUILD_NUMBER"
agvtool new-version -all "${BUILD_NUMBER}"

# XCODE make sure buildpath exists for configuration, build if missing
BUILDPATH="build/$CONFIGURATION-iphoneos"
build_xcode 
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: xcodebuild not successful"
    exit 1
fi
if test ! -d "$BUILDPATH"; then
    echo "ERROR: xcodebuild could not build configuration $CONGIRUATION ($BUILDPATH)"
exit
fi
echo "=== Successfully built configuration $CONFIGURATION ($BUILDPATH)"

# HACK : accomodate configurations with spaces, chdir to determine app name
cd "$BUILDPATH"
# derive name of .app dir (application)
APPDIR=`ls -d *.app`
cd ../..

APPPATH="$BUILDPATH/$APPDIR"
DSYMPATH="$BUILDPATH/$APPDIR.dSYM"
if test "$APPDIR"x = x; then
    APPPATH="$BUILDPATH/.app"
fi


# XCODE make sure app dir exists in buildpath, build if missing
if test ! -d "$APPPATH"; then

    echo "missing $APPPATH build in $BUILDPATH, trying to build"
    build_xcode

    # HACK : accomodate configurations with spaces, chdir to determine app name
    cd "$BUILDPATH"
    # derive name of .app dir (application)
    APPDIR=`ls -d *.app`
    cd ../..

    # check again for APPDIR/APPPATH
    APPPATH="$BUILDPATH/$APPDIR"
    if test "$APPDIR"x = x; then
        APPPATH="$BUILDPATH/.app"
    fi

    if test ! -d "$APPPATH"; then
        echo "ERROR: xcodebuild could not build $APPPATH configuration $CONGIRUATION ($BUILDPATH)"
        exit
    fi
    echo "=== Successfully built $APPDIR configuration $CONFIGURATION ($BUILDPATH)"
fi

# Create directory for release package
echo " -  Creating release dir"
RELEASEDIR="$RELEASEBASE/$RELEASE-$CONFIGURATION-$MARKETING_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER"
mkdir -p "$RELEASEDIR"

echo "RELEASEDIR = $RELEASEDIR"
echo "BUILDPATH = $BUILDPATH"
echo "APPPATH = $APPPATH"
echo "DSYMPATH = $APPPATH"

# Copy other files
cp $DISTDIR/* "$RELEASEDIR"

# .IPA file: iphone app archive file, installable by itunes
IPA=`echo $APPDIR | sed "s/\.app/\.ipa/"`
echo " -  Creating $IPA payload"
mkdir -p "$RELEASEDIR/Payload/"
echo " - Copying $APPPATH to $RELEASEDIR/Payload/"
# Copy built .app to payload/ itunes-specific install dir
cp -Rp "$APPPATH" "$RELEASEDIR/Payload/"

# Build .IPA file
#   this is just a zipfile with a payload/ dir with the .app, and artwork
cd "$RELEASEDIR"
# include 512x512 png of artwork, if foudn
if test -f "iTunesArtwork"; then
    zip -y -r "$IPA" iTunesArtwork Payload/
    rm -rf Payload iTunesArtwork
else 
    zip -y -r "$IPA" Payload/
    rm -rf Payload 
fi

cd ..
pwd
# Create .zip packaged Distribution
ZIPFILE="$RELEASE-$CONFIGURATION-$MARKETING_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER.zip"
DSYMZIPFILE="$RELEASE-$CONFIGURATION-$MARKETING_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER-dSYM.zip"
echo " -  zipfile is $ZIPFILE"
echo " -  Compressing release $ZIPFILE"
zip -y -r "$ZIPFILE" "$RELEASE-$CONFIGURATION-$MARKETING_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER"
cp -pR "../$DSYMPATH" "$RELEASE-$CONFIGURATION-$MARKETING_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER"
echo " - creating zip of dSYM file"
zip -y -r "$DSYMZIPFILE" "$RELEASE-$CONFIGURATION-$MARKETING_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER/$APPDIR.dSYM"
cd ..

echo "=== Build complete for $RELEASEBASE/$ZIPFILE"
```

Then, my hudson configuration looks like this:

```
./build.sh AdHoc
./build.sh Release
```

Finally, my files to archive looks like this:

```
_release/MobilePracticePro-*-${BUILD_NUMBER}*.zip
```

Hope this is helpful to you! Using Hudson is really great. Also, realize your signing key needs to be installed on the same box as hudson runs and running as same user. At least that is how it is for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue and resolved by using the steps give in the details of the link  [Xcode "Build and Archive" from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line/18353490#18353490)