# To automate xcode 'Build and Archive'

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, continuous-integration, build-automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode “Build and Archive” from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line)

can anyone please specify me the steps to Automate the xcode 'Build and Archive' option using command line
I need to do that by setting the provisioning profile
Any help is appreciated.

Regards,