# Archive with Xcode's command line build tool (xcodebuild archive)

Tags: ios, command-line, xcode4, xcodebuild

The command line tool to build Xcode projects, xcodebuild, has a new build action available in Xcode 4: `archive`.

From `man xcodebuild`:

```
       archive     Archive a scheme from the build root (SYMROOT).  This requires specifying
                   a workspace and scheme.
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use it I get an error:

```
$ xcodebuild archive -workspace SimpleTestApp.xcworkspace -scheme SimpleTestApp
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace SimpleTestApp with scheme SimpleTestApp.
    Reason: The selected run destination is not valid for this action.
```

My impression is this doesn't actually work yet. Has anyone got it to work? If so, how?

Comment: Anyone knows how to start xcodebuild archive?

Comment: Yeah, I'm calling it against a workspace not a project.

Comment: Are you able to build fine from within xcode?

Comment: Yes, it works fine within the IDE. But I want to automate my build.

Comment: Make sure the name of the scheme is exactly the same. my scheme was called "MyProject Ent" in Xcode and from command line I was calling "MyProjectEnt" and that was not correct. Edit this is "Manage Schemes"

Comment: It probably would have worked if you'd quoted it, too: `-scheme "MyProject Ent"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For information I'm 99% sure that `xcodebuild archive` was working in a previous Xcode 4 version, maybe a `Beta`...
And this is really frustrating since `-verbose` and syslogs doesn't bring much details.

So I would call that... a Bug!

If automating your build is what you are looking for, there is a way to [generate IPA archive from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line) using `xcrun PackageApplication`

With `xcrun` to package and `xcodebuild` to build, you can almost achieve what `xcodebuild archive` is supposed to do. I would prefer to use `xcodebuild` since we can expect this to generate a `.xcarchive` (`.app` + `.dSYM`), more interesting than an IPA.

Not so off-topic, but if anyone knows how to get more logs from xcodebuild and Xcode, I'm really interested!

**EDIT**:
After looking [in Apple Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/391886), I confirm this is an Xcode BUG introduced with GM2... I guess Apple Xcode engineers are working on Xcode 4.1 that I think final version will be released with OSX Lion... In june maybe? With a fix? :(

Comment: That's my forum thread. :) It seems like what I want isn't possible at this point.

Comment: Haha, I should have checked names! That is bogging me too, I love archives concept, and the simplification it brings for AppStore submission, but would love too to automate this in the beta stage! >_<

Comment: It seems to be broken again in 4.3.2: `unsupported build action 'archive'` :(

Comment: I've abandoned the idea of using this a long time ago... and use Xcode IDE to do this... man `xcodebuild` still mention `archive` as a valid `buildaction`... sounds like a bug... again.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work for me:

```
xcodebuild -project TestApp.xcodeproj  -scheme TestApp -configuration "Ad Hoc" archive
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this working from the GUI ?
Project -> Build for Archive
Then you can find the archive back in Organizer (archive Tab) 
It is working for me in the GUI

Comment: Yeah, it works fine in the GUI. xcodebuild is the name of the command line component to do it. I'm clarifying this a bit in the question, thanks.