# Xcode command line build fails with "Failed to read entitlements"

Tags: xcode, jenkins, clang

My Jenkins (continues integration server) is failing with the error:

```
error: Failed to read entitlements from '/var/folders/gp/fxfq69kd26j160s85g6vjy6h0000gr/T/yMWJTWS2AJ/Payload/app.com.app'
```

Full output:

> The following build commands failed:
>          CompileC /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-doozayqorsxatsbzlunnptqszxax/Build/Intermediates/rara.build/Production-iphoneos/rara.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RRArtworkView.o
>   app/RRArtworkView.m normal armv7 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure) Poduct build
>   dir:
>   /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-doozayqorsxatsbzlunnptqszxax/Build/Products/Production-iphoneos
>   xcrun via /usr/bin/xcrun (xcrun) DEVELOPER_DIR = '/Developer' via
>   '/usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_path' Database Key is:
>   PackageApplication_***/Developer***_iphoneos Cache version is '1'
>   Lookup resolved in
>   '/var/folders/gp/fxfq69kd26j160s85g6vjy6h0000gr/T/xcrun_db' :
>   '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication'
>   error: Failed to read entitlements from
>   '/var/folders/gp/fxfq69kd26j160s85g6vjy6h0000gr/T/yMWJTWS2AJ/Payload/app.com.app'
>   Build "app" failed Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

It build fine form the IDE and will install on the device.

### System info:

- Xcode v4.3.2

Comment: possible dupe of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384999/archive-with-xcodes-command-line-build-tool-xcodebuild-archive

Comment: @rishi that was caused by a bug in an old version of Xcode

Comment: That's Ok. One more thing, entitlements.plist is no longer necessary after Xcode 4, so you can archive your app without that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The rather cryptic message:

> Failed to read entitlements[...]

Is cause by Xcode not archiving the app correctly, this is normally caused by:

1. Having **"Skip Install"** set to `NO`
2. Have header file (.h) copied to a public folder in the build phase

See the question:

#### [Compile, Build or Archive problems with Xcode 4 (and dependancies)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607376/89035)

For a detailed explanation of these issues.