# Adding a new target in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, target

I am just trying to add a new target to my project in xcode 4.2. After selecting Add target option, i have n't see any External build system option in ios section.Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had success by creating an OS X external build system, then changing the SDKROOT under Build Settings to "iphoneos".  It causes many other build settings to change magically to reasonable values for iOS.  I've used this technique with success in the past with Xcode 4.0.2, and I'm using it right now with Xcode 4.3.2 to build executables for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

External build system projects and targets are not currently available for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Select the project file.. then, `File->New->New Target` in xcode 4.2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just go to project settings and select your newly created target. Then you'll be able to see your new settings there. Plus, you can checkout [this tutorial-blog](http://caplesscoder.blogspot.com/2013/09/xcode-project-with-two-different-targets.html) about creating a new target in an existing app, it'll give you all the hints and you'll see best practices there