# Tagging XCode's Archive builds in Git or another SCM

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, build

I'd like my XCode Archive builds to automatically tag my SCM (Git in this project).

I've noticed that in the Schema Editor, **Archive builds can run pre and post step build scripts**. It would be ideal if post steps are only run if the build is successful, and then the tag could go there.

I'd like the tag name to refer to the name of the build configuration (I have TestFlight and AppStore configurations, as well as Debug and Release, which would not normally be archived), as well as the version number that was built, and also the build number. A tag might go something like: `TestFlight_2.1.3_#11` or `AppStore_2.9.0_#3`.

In XCode's project settings, you can use variable substitutions, such as `$(BUILD_CONFIGURATION)`. **Can these be used in an Archive build script?**

I'm also not sure if there is a **variable for the current version string and build number** of the App. I've not managed to find one if there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In XCode's project settings, you can use variable substitutions, such as $(BUILD_CONFIGURATION). Can these be used in an Archive build script?

Yes. Build settings are available as environment variables to scripts that run as part of a Run Script Build Phase. An easy way to see what variables are set (if you don't trust the build log output) is to just put `env` in a script to print them out, or `env > environment.txt` if you want to save them to a file.

> I'm also not sure if there is a variable for the current version string and build number of the App. I've not managed to find one if there is.

There is not. However, if you want to retrieve the current version you can get it from the project's Info.plist file (and there should be an environment variable pointing to the file for the active project).

Xcode Archive doesn't have a concept of a current build number. Usually you use a script to figure out the build number from some other source (Xcode Server, a counter on your disk, whatever) and then set the CFBundleVersion key in Info.plist to that number.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In the Archives window, my archives have a name, a creation date, and a version with a version string and a build number, such as `2.5 (20)` – the `20` is what I meant of as the "build number", and hoped to gain access to – this could be found in the info.plist, though?

Comment: Yes, those numbers are being pulled from Info.plist and will be whatever you set them to be. They don't auto-increment with every build; you'd have to figure out a way to do that yourself. Look up `agvtool` for one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
https://github.com/bejo/XcodeIconTagger

Obviously this is not exactly what you asked, as this will tag the icon, but you could probably use it to point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for this, by the way – I've got a moment to take a look now!