# Add Run Script Phase only for Debug Configuration XCode 3.2

Tags: xcode

I want a run a script post-build for an XCode 3.2 project, so I added a "Run Script" phase to my target. It works great, but I only want to run this script in the Debug configuration, does anyone know how to do this?

thx,
A

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer, it looks to do what you are looking for. [Running script only for an 'Archive' build in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471396/running-script-only-for-an-archive-build-in-xcode-4)