# Xcode - How can we get the current time (Create time) when archive in xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, archive

my app has an About dialog that displaying the content as "Build time: 2013/05/14 14:20". The "Build time" can update when archive. I can update it manually, but sometime I forget it. I try to research how to update "build time" when archive like this: 
[Running script only for an 'Archive' build in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471396/running-script-only-for-an-archive-build-in-xcode-4)

I hope your helps!

p/s: Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not populate the About box with values of the predefined C (string) macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` rather than setting them manually?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I mean that "Build time" only update when archive app from xcode.

Comment: @thanhzusu If you use `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` then it will update whenever you rebuild the code that populates the About content.  You might just need to do a clean first before archiving.