# Before building app remove a simple key from Info.plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Actually based on configuration I want to remove and add one key in Info.plist. To make it dynamic. I have taken approach of Adding a script to accomplish this.

What I tried and what problem I faced is here.

**Added a Build Script:**  Added script using Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Run script.

*Output*: I can see key is deleted in Xcode file but when I am going to see it in iPA key is still there. So, I believe Build system has copied that file before deleting the key.  Looks like issue in sequence of executing script.

**Pre-Action Build scheme** is looks promising.

*Problem*: I added simple echo statement in Pre-Action script. But I am not able to see it’s output. On few question of stack overflow I found that we can see it on console.app. But I tried lot I am not able to see it in Console.app.  I am using Xcode 5.1.1.

Anybody can point out where can I see output of my pre-action script?

**External Build System:** I also tried this [Running script only for an 'Archive' build in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471396/running-script-only-for-an-archive-build-in-xcode-4)

*Problem in solution provided in above link*:

1. Not sure how to provide path of script file relative to project
2. Not able to find environment variable like ${INFOPLIST_File}

Comment: In my project I increment CFBundleVersion in Run script just after "Target Dependencies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to create a new target using the *External Build System* template (and make it run the script) and then make the app/library/whatever target dependent on this new target.

That way it will be run before Xcode even touches your `Info.plist` and there used to be issues with Xcode (in 4.2 if I remember right) where running scripts that modified the `Info.plist` in a build phase would make it crash.

I use this approach to build spritesheets using the TexturePacker command line and to bump my build number using a python script.

**EDIT** Here's an example of the settings to use, assuming the script is in a directory called `tools` (my preferred location) in a sibling directory to the Xcode Project, so:

```
MyProject/
    MyProject.xcodeproj/
    MyProject/
        (source files)
        MyProject-Info.plist
    tools/
        the_script.sh             (see below)
```

Then the *External Build System* would be configured with:

```
Build Tool: tools/the_script.sh
Arguments: MyTarget1/MyTarget1-Info.plist MyTarget2/MyTarget2-Info.plist
Working Directory: $(SRCROOT)
```

Then `the_script.sh` will expect the `Info.plist` path as its only argument (don't forget to `chmod 0755` before running it):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Don't do anything when cleaning
if [ "$ACTION" = "clean" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo usage: $0 info-plist \[ ... info-plist \]
    exit 1
fi

while (( "$#" )); do

    plist=$1

    # Do work
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ... $plist

    shift
done
```

Comment: Already tried this. Previously question was not formatted properly. But now it is clearly saying what issues I am facing in you mentioned approach.

Comment: @Iducool I have updated my answer with some example settings.

Comment: Any way to get build dynamic path of plist. As I have lots of targets. I tried to use $INFOPLIST_FILE and $INFOPLIST_PATH. but its not working

Comment: That will be similar to the script I used to bump my build number then (except that uses Python) and what I do is pass the path to every `Info.plist` file on the command line and the script iterates through them.  Won't be too hard to modify.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Iducool OK updated; the reason you cannot use `$INFOPLIST_FILE` is that the *External Build System* is its own target with potentially its own `Info.plist` file, so you have to explicitly name each `Info.plist` file when invoking the script.