# Programmatically remove all local Swift Packages before archiving

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I have modularized much of my code base into Swift Packages, and use local packages as described by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/editing-a-package-dependency-as-a-local-package) to do most of my work.  I would like to automatically remove these local packages as step before archiving.  I believe this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471396/running-script-only-for-an-archive-build-in-xcode-4) should work as a "pre" archive action, but I am unsure how to actually remove the local packages programatically.

Comment: Remove them from where? Why?  Source code is not included in the app archive but you will need the packages to actually build your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 remove them as local packages. So the actual tagged version is used rather than the local package which may have changes I am not ready to commit/tag. Ie. step #6 in the Apple reference.

Comment: This sounds like something you should manage via git/version control. The project in your main/release branch would not use local packages. You would use local packages in your feature/development branches. When you want to create a release your merge the changes into your main/release branch and archive from that.