# How do I archive multiple targets with one action in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, xcode4

I have a project with multiple targets that are all for different iOS Apps. For instance one traget for the lite version and another one for the pro version.

I want to build and archive all of my Apps at once. Currently I have a scheme for every target which I use to archive each app independently. But now I have to start the archiving, wait until it is done and then start the next one.

Is there a way to archive all apps with one single action in xcode 4 or using the command line?

Answer (score 5):

The Build action in a scheme dictates what targets are built for what actions. Leave the defaults (so they'll all be built for the Archive action). When that scheme is active, it'll build all the requested targets just prior to archiving when you select Product -> Archive.

You could create a new scheme called "All", edit it, then in its Build action, add all targets you want to archive. Then just select that scheme and ask it to archive.

Alternatively, add all targets to your existing scheme and uncheck unwanted actions for which it should build those extra targets, leaving only Archive.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, because one of the libraries (three20) I am using will not find half of the header files when compiling. But everything compiles just fine if I build all the targets independently.

Comment: What if you create an aggregate target. Select project, click Add Target, choose Other category, select Aggregate target type and set it up.

Comment: This solution from Joshua is so close, except if you archive, you archive the bundle, not a bunch of ipa's

Comment: I agree. So close. You can even export the generated archive into separate product files, but they're unfortunately .app files, not .ipa files. :(

Comment: To be fair, it's a solution from Apple. I'm just a messenger. :-D

Comment: Did any of you find a good solution to this? I have about 10 white label apps I have targets for all in one Xcode project, would love to build individual archives in one click.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xcodebuild` from the commandline

e.x.
`xcodebuild -configuration Release -project MyProject -scheme MyProjectScheme clean build`

Also you can use `xcrun` to build an ipa from the commandline as well, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198166/618419

Comment: Have you tested this in multiple terminal windows?