# Xcode4: Alternative Way to build IPAs

Tags: ios, xcode4, ipa

So with XCode4, as is kinda well known, building .IPAs can only be created used "build and archive" if only one target has "Skip Install" set to "No".
My problem is that our project contains multiple targets, that need to be shipped as .ipas at some point. Setting "Skip Install" on each on everytime i need to build an .ipa is annoying. Does anybody know of a better way, maybe using those scary "Configuration Files" I've seen mentioned somewhere? Currently, i'm using the .app from the .xarchive and build an .IPA the old way, packaging it in a Payload folder.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about xcrun PackageApplication?

- [Xcode “Build and Archive” from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line/4198166#4198166)

Execute xcrun from command line.

```
PRODUCTDIR=DerivedData/foo/Build/Products/AdHoc-iphoneos
TARGET=targetA
IDENTITY="iPhone\ Distribution:\ foo"
PROVISIONING_PROFILE="/Users/foo/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/foo.mobileprovision"
OUTDIR=out
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${PRODUCTDIR}/${TARGET}.app" -o "${OUTDIR}/${TARGET}.ipa" --sign "${IDENTITY}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}"
```

Comment: what exactly is the Identity? What kind of string to you give?

Comment: like this. "iPhone Distribution: Foo Co.,Ltd."

Comment: Beware of not generating the ipa in the current directory (ie -o ./foo.ipa or -o foo.ipa) or it will be removed when the script ends.

Comment: OUTDIR must be an absolute path, e.g. OUTDIR=\`pwd\`/${PRODUCTDIR}

Comment: @GrahamPerks:can u elaborate a little bit more on ur code i.e
 OUTDIR=`pwd`/${PRODUCTDIR}

Comment: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory

Comment: can you please tell how to use it?

Comment: I've been doing this all along but now with watch apps and extensions does this change in any way?

Answer (score 0):

How about define several targets? That should you allow to adjust each separately for your needs.

Comment: i have multiple targets. But every target has to have "Skip Install" set to "No"