# Automate OSX Mac App Store builds

Tags: macos, build-automation

I'm looking for a way to automate the "Build and Archive" and "Organizer->Share.." for my OSX Mac App Store builds.  I have read through "[Xcode “Build and Archive” from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line)" which is specific to iPhone development, and I'm hoping something similar can be done for my builds.

Answer (score 3):

question from long ago.

It looks like now you can use [Application Loader](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW1) to upload binaries in addition to using XCode. Buried in the (PDF!) documentation for Application Loader is reference to a Unix build tool embedded deep in the package.

It means I can add some code to my build Makefile:

```
ALTOOL:="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool"

$ALTOOL --validate-app -f Surfwriter.app.zip -u $APPSTORE_USERNAME -p $APPSTORE_PASSWORD
$ALTOOL --upload-app -f Surfwriter.app.zip -u $APPSTORE_USERNAME -p $APPSTORE_PASSWORD
```

Of course, before you submit `Surfwriter.app.zip` you have to build the binary and sign it (should be able to use `xcodebuild` for that)

This should theoretically do the trick for you.