# Use the aggregate target to sign and deploy multiple apps

Tags: xcode

I have an XCode project with multiple target that compiles some shared source code file, in addition to specific .xib files. Basically each target builds a different app, but under the hood, most of the code is shared.

I would like a way to automate the deployement of these apps. Currently, I need to select the target in the scheme drop down, select Product > Archive, click share, select the appropriate code signing certificate and a location, then deploy my .ipa.

I think I need to use an Aggregate that builds all my targets and [use `xcrun` as seen in this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line) as a script run in the build phase of each target, but I'm blocked at the code signing part. I found the `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` in the Build Setting section of the [Xcode Build Setting Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html). **How can I programmatically access the Provisioning Profile specified in each target's Build Settings ?**

I guess a last resort would be to store the profiles in a know directory relative to my source code path

Answer (score 0):

To access it from a script / from the CLI just pass the name you get from the `CODE_SIGN_IDENTY` to the `codesign` program :)

e.g.:
`sign='codesign -s "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTY" "$PATH_TO_APP"'`

---

to do it programmatically via Objective C use the **KeyChain API** to find the item named CODE_SIGN_IDENTY. This is what the code sign CLI app does as well