# xcodebuild: build Mac OS app

Tags: xcode, macos, archive, xcodebuild

I'd like to do automating for my  **Mac** App project.

My environment is Mac OS 10.8.3; Xcode 4.6.
I use the following command in the terminal:

> xcodebuild -project pro.xcodeproj -target MyProject -configuration Debug  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='Mac Developer: xxxxxx'

It ran well and I could see the MyProject.app was created in the workspace: /build/Debug.

Then I just copied it to the Jenkins configurations, like:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
xcodebuild -project pro.xcodeproj -target MyProject -configuration Debug  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='Mac Developer: xxxxxx'
```

However, the build always failed with :

> Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'EADA149E-1A30-4C3C-B42B-75DEA77308DF' can't be found

What makes me strange is that I could not find the "wrong" profile.

I find a same question [Distributing .app file after command line xcodebuild call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366304/distributing-app-file-after-command-line-xcodebuild-call). But the "archive" is invalid in xcode 4.6.

So please help me about how can I do the automating for **Mac App**.
Thanks!

Comment: can you build your app on that machine *without* using a script, i.e. just the traditional way of doing "Build" or "Archiving"?

Comment: yes, I can. It just does not work in the shell of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it and it is the same problem like "provison not found".
What you need to do is delete the referred provision file in prom.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.

You can find the same answers here [Codesign error: Provisioning profile cannot be found after deleting expired profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760518/codesign-error-provisioning-profile-cannot-be-found-after-deleting-expired-prof)