# Xcodebuild Archive Location

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, archive, xcodebuild

I'm currently trying to build an .xcarchive using this command line:

```
xcodebuild -project onething.xcodeproj -target onething archive
```

This places the .xcarchive within a hard to find file location, so I was wondering if there's a configuration to be able to set the file location for the archive?

Comment: See if this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722633/generate-xcarchive-into-a-specific-folder-from-the-command-line helps

Answer (score 16):

xcode->preferences->locations->archieves

[image: archieve change]

Answer (score 9):

xcodebuild now takes an `-archivePath` argument. Use this to explicitly define where the archive will be output. Note that if this is used Organizer will not be able to find the file.

[xcodebuild man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html)

Comment: It writes nothing in that folder, do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Xcode open Project and go to Build setting , find enable Bitcode , by default its is YES make it is as NO and save

also check in build.json packageType match with Apple id Certificate i.e. Development