# Can a xcarchive file be created from a ipa file?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, ipa, xcarchive

If you have an ipa file (e.g. generated through Jenkins), can you create an archive out of it? Is there a possibility to do that in Xamarin Studio/Xcode after the ipa file has been created?

Or is the only way generating a new ipa/xcarchive file in Xamarin Studio/Xcode? Perhaps the xcarchive can be build on the command line with the ipa file path as input parameter?

There is [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20905823/426227), which can create a xcarchive file

```
xcodebuild -scheme myscheme archive -archivePath /path/to/AppName.xcarchive
```

but what is the project source for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The xcarchive includes dSYM information that is not included in the ipa-file.

The `archive` command uses the archive action in the scheme specified on the command line. The project is either guessed by `xcodebuild` or specified as a command line parameter.

Comment: So `xcodebuild` is only available for Xcode projects then (e.g. xcodeproj, xcworkspace)?

Comment: @testing Yes. But I guess you can create an xcarchive manually if you have the DWARF/dSYM file. It is mostly a few folders, a dSYM-file, an app and some Info.plist-files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instructions for an iOS app:

1. Create a folder named `%(AppName).xcarchive`.
2. Create an `Info.plist` in the root of the following format. Replace all the `%(...)` values with the proper ones for your application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ApplicationProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ApplicationPath</key>
        <string>Applications/%(AppName).app</string>
        <key>Architectures</key>
        <array>
            <string>arm64</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>%(bundle_identifier)</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>%(marketing_version)</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>SigningIdentity</key>
        <string>%(name_or_identifier_of_signing_identity)</string>
        <key>Team</key>
        <string>%(team_identifier)</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ArchiveVersion</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2022-05-18T23:56:29Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>%(AppName)</string>
    <key>SchemeName</key>
    <string>Empty</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

3. Unzip the built `.ipa`.
4. Copy the `SwiftSupport` and `MessagesApplicationExtensionSupport` in the root of the decompressed IPA into the root of the `.xcarchive`.
5. Copy the `.app` from the IPA into the `.xcarchive/Products/Applications` folder in the XCArchive.

This allows me to run commands like `xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /path/to/AppName.xcarchive -exportPath AppName -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptionsPlist.plist` on the manually created IPA (that doesn't contain dSYMs).