# Using script to generate many binary using xcode

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-organizer

I have a project that I need to generate many iPhone apps, but they all with different name, icons, etc.

It will share the same code based but it will be deploy under different project name.

For example:

```
The project: editions =>  
    Mag1_editions (com.foo.mag1_editions),   
    Mag2_editions (com.foo.mag2_editions),
```

I would like put this into script, so I can execute once and all the binary will be archive in organizer ready to be published.

I have tried target, xcodebuild, scheme, build settings, but none of them works for my need.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Holy Molly! I guess there are legitimate uses for this! I can't imagine them but there should be.

Comment: I needed for newsstand apps. The code for each NK apps is the same, but the settings, icons, etc will be specific to each magazines. We have them stored in database, I am using python script to build it. 

I need to be able to pass parameter into xcodebuild -scheme scheme archive, but it currently ignore all of params.

Comment: Thanks, now I can imagine the use cases, just for my information, you need to make a new archive for every issue or one for every magazine/journal?

Comment: one for every journal/ magazine. They all shared the same code, just different settings.

Answer (score 0):

See [Xcode "Build and Archive" from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line). Also read the blog post the highly-rated answer links to. It should include everything you need. I just built a very similar script this morning.

Comment: Thanks Rob for answering, I actually read this one, but I can build it fine, but when I need to put into the archive mode, I can no longer able to pass arguments into the xcodebuild     

xcodebuild -scheme schemename archive TARGET_NAME=foo, will ignore all of the arguments (TARGET_NAME), There is a similar question in stackoverlow about this "bug".

How can I make it to appear into organizer, do I need xcrun ?

Comment: Basically I don't want an .ipa file, I would like to have it in xcarchive format. Should I use xcrun to package it ?