# Archiving the project from terminal

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have seen posts regarding building a project from terminal.But I would like to archive the project and create a `.ipa` file in the specified folder of my wish.

For that, I presume I need developer certificate, provisioning profile, sdk, architecture, projectName etc.

```
I could specify below things,
Project Name: I go to project folder or I will give the path
SDK: ios4.0, likewise.
architecture: arm6,7 etc.
```

But how should I specify certificates? Should I give paths with names or Ids.
And are there anything more have to be done for that? I mean plain layout of what has to be done, would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this is what you're looking for: Xcode “Build and Archive” from command line][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line)

Comment: I hope that shows up right, I'm doing this from an ipad. URL is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line