# Automated iOS App Deployment & Testing

Tags: ios, testing, deployment, command-line, installation

I am building a mobile device test-rig that will deploy a mobile app that we have created to **REAL** Android and iOS devices. We've got a bunch of devices and USB cables and USB hubs plugged into a machine :)

The mobile app will automatically run all unit tests on deployment and we have builds for both android and iOS. Deploying to multiple devices requires scripting and using command-line tools for installation.

For Android this is easy - using Android Debug Bridge (adb).

For iOS, there seems to be nothing out there for installing an iOS app to a **REAL** iOS device from the command-line.

Please, please please somebody out there let me know of a tool to do it!

Thanks very much for reading!

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line