# issues with TeamCity, xcrun and single quotes

Tags: iphone, ios, continuous-integration, teamcity, xcrun

I'm using TeamCity with xcrun for CI on an IOS project.  I'm currently seeing an issues while trying to execute the following command from a TC build step:

```
-sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "Build/Release-iphoneos/%Product Name%.app" -o "%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/Build/archive.ipa" --sign "iPhone Distribution: AMERICA'S XXXX" --embed "%Provision File%"
```

The error I get is:

> error: /usr/bin/codesign --force
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign "iPhone Distribution: AMERICA'S
>   --resource-rules=/Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/PotQjg91Ef/Payload/ACCU
>   Deposit.app/ResourceRules.plist
>   /Library/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp/PotQjg91Ef/Payload/ACCU
>   Deposit.app failed with error 1. Output: "iPhone Distribution:
>   AMERICA'S: no identity found [2013-05-16 14:58:46,533] err - 
>   [2013-05-16 14:58:46,533] out -  [2013-05-16 14:58:46,540] out -
>   Process exited with code 1

I think is pretty clear that the issue is the way xcrun handles single quotes.  I tried doubling the single quote to "AMERICA''S" but that didn't work.  Can someone help me out?  Is there a way to escape single quotes in xcrun?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the sign entity `iPhone Distribution: AMERICA'S XXXX` to make it as only one argument for `--sign`, otherwise it would be divided by whitespaces and be recognized only the first part. That's what `PackageApplication` do to recognize command arguments.

I do not know the grammar of your command, but it seems that you should put `iPhone Distribution: AMERICA'S XXXX` in a variable like `%Sign Entity%`. Then the whole command should be like this:

`-sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "Build/Release-iphoneos/%Product Name%.app" -o "%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/Build/archive.ipa" --sign "%Sign Entity%" --embed "%Provision File%"`

Answer (score -1):

Try "iPhone Distribution: AMERICA\'S XXXX".