# Generate IPA File From terminal

Tags: terminal, archive, ipa

```
xcrun -sdk  iphoneos6.1 PackageApplication -v "/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/mobi/Mob/build/Debug-iphoneos/Mob.app" -o "/Users/salmannasir/Documents/Projects//mobi/IPAFolder/Mobi234.ipa" --sign "iPhone Developer: Derek Sine (TFJ34N54U5)" --embed "/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/mobi/Mob/DC983365-9967-4F0D-9004-71AFB5450B92.mobileprovision"
```

i got error :

```
rogram /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/var/folders/rx/rxc18xvx6vl59pgn2d8yzx3m0000gn/T/HKxz0onJOS/Payload/Mobi.app: replacing existing signature
/var/folders/rx/rxc18xvx6vl59pgn2d8yzx3m0000gn/T/HKxz0onJOS/Payload/Mobi.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
]
error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Developer: Derek Sine (TFJ34N3SU5) --resource-rules=/var/folders/rx/rxc18xvx6vl59pgn2d8yzx3m0000gn/T/HKxz0onJOS/Payload/Mobi.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/rx/rxc18xvx6vl59pgn2d8yzx3m0000gn/T/HKxz0onJOS/Payload/Mobi.app failed with error 1. Output: /var/folders/rx/rxc18xvx6vl59pgn2d8yzx3m0000gn/T/HKxz0onJOS/Payload/Mobi.app: replacing existing signature
/var/folders/rx/rxc18xvx6vl59pgn2d8yzx3m0000gn/T/HKxz0onJOS/Payload/Mobi.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

this issue was in  `-o "/Users/salmannasir/Documents/Projects//mobi/IPAFolder/Mobi234.ipa"`

Can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

The path u specified is the output directory where u need to store the .ipa file of your project and also i think the command and parameters you are using is also not correct.

if u are still facing same problem u can visit this link for more details

[Xcode "Build and Archive" from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line/18353490#18353490)