# iOS command-line build: How to create xcode archive from command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line-tool

I am using below command to create an signed ipa file from command line i.e. terminal.

***xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication \
    "path/to/build/MyApp.app" \
    -o "output/path/to/MyApp.ipa" \
    --sign "iPhone Distribution: My Company" \
    --embed "path/to/something.mobileprovision"***

As understood from above, this will create an ipa file. But, I want to create a xcarchive file which will be used to upload to app store using Application Loader. How can I modify this command to achieve that. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode "Build and Archive" from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `xcodebuild archive` command

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit of what archive does internally. Does it do code signing also? Another thing is after **xcodebuild archive**, where will the xcarchive be stored? I want to store it in my own defined path.