# Best Practice for customizing Cordova Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, npm, command-line-interface

I'm working on a Cordova project that requires me to replace my main.m file with a .mm file and - along with adding a custom build phase script. When I do this I can no longer use the cordova cli commands or cleanly upgrade my cordova project when new versions are released.

I can't seem to find any documentation on editing things at this level. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've looked into the cordova hooks but I'm not sure whether that would work or where to hook my code to ensure a proper build.

Comment: Is the custom build phase script an xcode IDE specific thing, or can it be run from the command line?

Comment: It relays on build parameters so I'd assume that its IDE specific. Unless there's some way that I'm unaware of.

Comment: You can do some xcode building from the command line.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line  Unless you can do that build phase script from the command line, you're locked into the IDE, so I'd investigate that before writing any hooks.  (I think a hook is the right place to do this in cordova cli.)

Answer (score 0):

- Fork the Cordova-iOS and maintain your changes there. Merge commits from the original apache repo from time to time.
- Use `cordova platform add your-fork-git-url#branch-or-tag` to add platform

I hope it can help