# Dynamic archive name in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I'm updating my archive process to make it easier to use.

I already created some schemes and build configurations that avoid me to manually update constants between 2 archives, but now I want to go deeper.

When I edit a scheme, the "Archive" section allow us to set an archive name. By default it's set to the scheme name, but I'd like to have it dynamic. For example, I'd like it to be like:

```
<CFBundleIdentifier>-<CFBundleShortVersionString>-<CFBundleVersion>
```

Is that even possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Also need it. Did you find the solution? Thanks

Comment: @GeRyCh Nope unfortunately :/

Comment: Here someone uses it for CI deployment. He read it into parameter from Info.plist & changes the app name after in installation plist. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10981634/705617

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible.

Also if you are planning to upload the app to AppStore, check the apple's [AppStore review guideline.](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be
>   similar, so as not to cause confusion

**Note:**

Instead of changing name in Scheme, you can go to target's Build Settings -> Product name and set the name there.

Comment: I don't want to change the Product name, it's already set. I just want to automatically change the archive name I send to the client for testing, so that he knows which version of the app he's installing.

Comment: @Imotep : You can add that in settings app (your app's settings), right ? It can be dynamically generated. I'm doing that for my builds.

Comment: yeah I could, but I just want the app version to be in the .ipa name, so that we don't have to install the app to know which version it is.