# Xcode organizer trying to access transporter at wrong directory path

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

`Transporter not found at path: /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter.
You should reinstall the application.`

So I checked the path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin` and iTMSTransporter exists there (where it is installed with xcode). The path given to me in the error is where transporter is installed if you install it manually. How do I make it so that when I try and submit my app xcode organizer uses the path were iTMSTransporter is installed through xcode? I'm baffled why it is doing this in the first place.

Comment: I am running into the same issue with  Xcode 6.3 (6D520o). I have filed a bug with apple (19812248) and i encourage you to do the same. I have also started a thread on the apple developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/262064?tstart=0

Comment: Will Do. A work around for now is to download the transporter from itunesconnect.

Comment: Through the Xcode 6.3 Beta's Organizer, I exported and chose "Save for iOS App Store Deployment".

I was able to open the application `/Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/Application\ Loader`, and deliver the exported app, but got the same error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem and made a symlink from the location XCode expected the iTMSTransporter to the location in the Applications folder you mentioned:

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms /usr/local/itms
```

However, when uploading my binary I get the error:

> [ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."

Digging some deeper into Console.app, I found the following error message:

> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102
>
> INFO: Done performing authentication.
>
> INFO: The following info messages were received from Apple's web service ...
>
> INFO-X: INFO ITMS-90111: "Your app is built with a beta version of Xcode or iOS SDK. Only apps distributed for beta testing may be built with beta software. To submit an app for distribution on the App Store, you will need to build the app with release versions of Xcode and iOS SDK."
>
> DBG-X: Returning 1

But I haven't figured out a way to tell XCode that uploading for beta testing is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So even if you are using something like swift 1.1 that isn't beta you would get these errors when using beta XCode 6.3 beta even though it shouldn't compile it like swift 1.2?

Comment: I don't know exactly. The code that I was submitting contained Swift 1.2 code.

Comment: Upon reading the error message again, I don't think it's talking about Apple's Testflight beta testing here. It's just mentioning 'apps distributed for beta testing' (which was Ad Hoc only in the past). I think the error means: "You can't submit stuff to iTunes Connect that's build with beta versions of XCode or iOS" and probably predates Apple's TestFlight distribution.

Comment: I believe only the Segment Alignment ERRORs are keeping us from submitting to Testflight. The INFO message seems to only be letting you know that you can only Testflight the build, not submit for general release on the App Store.

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue? I am having the same"Invalid Segment Alignment" error when using "ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms /usr/local/itms
"

Comment: i am getting this also. When i look into itunes connect i see my app in the preselease section with the status "Invalid Binary"

Comment: You can't submit builds from beta versions such as xcode beta or swift 1.2. @Niels can you edit your answer so that this is clear to people?

Comment: As of Xcode 7.1, MacOS is no more in the itms folder path (edited the answer to remove it)

Comment: My xcode 8.2 drop the Application Loader.app for some reason, and I copy that from xcode 9, and looks works well.(Upload ok)

Answer (score 7):

Basically what the above answer stated but the symlink command was wrong for me. I used the following command to fix it:

`ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms/ /usr/local/itms`