# xcodebuild where is the output binary?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor

Sorry, I'm very new to iOS development.

I'm building a Cordova/Meteor app.  Meteor creates a build directory, and I'd like a command line script to build the binary to upload to itunesconnect.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="Michael"
NAME="appExpertAlerts"

# Create the xcode project
meteor add-platform ios
echo "STARTING BUILD"
meteor build ../../ops/production/ios \
  --mobile-settings ../../ops/production/meteor/settings.json \
  --server https://phone.app.io:443 \
  --verbose
meteor remove-platform ios
popd

# Build the xcode project
pushd ios/ios/project
xcodebuild \
  build \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  -configuration Release \
  -xcconfig cordova/build.xcconfig \
  -project "$NAME.xcodeproj" \
  -target "$NAME" \
  SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=$(pwd)/build/sharedpch \
  CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" \
  ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" \
  VALID_ARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64" \
  CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$(pwd)/build/device \

popd
```

The build says it's a success, and I can see output files, but I can't find the binary to upload to itunesconnect.

Where is the output binary?  Or how do I create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not yet implemented an automation of the build-upload to itunesconnect, sounds interesting :-)

Yet, after the build has been triggered, I think, what you try to achieve would be better implemented as a "run script" build phase. There you have the variables set as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW42

Especially interesting for you should be TARGET_BUILD_DIR:

TARGET_BUILD_DIR

> Description: Directory path. Identifies the root of the directory
> hierarchy that contains the product’s files (no intermediate build
> files).
>
> Run Script build phases that operate on product files of the
> target that defines them should use the value of this build setting.
> But Run Script build phases that operate on product files of other
> targets should use BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR instead.
>
> Example values:
> /Volumes/Users/genica/MyProject/build/Debug
> /tmp/MyProject.dst/Users/genica/Applications
> /Volumes/Users/genica/MyProject/build/UninstalledProducts Related to:
> DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION (Deployment Location), INSTALL_PATH (Installation
> Directory), SKIP_INSTALL.

The variables can be accessed as `${VAR NAME}` in your script.

The .ipa archive can be created as shown in this SO article: [Xcode "Build and Archive" from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line)

You may pay special attention to the `shenzen` tool, which is, if I understand you correctly, exactly what you are currently building. https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen