# XCodeBuild -exportArchive wont allow me to specify filename

Tags: swift, xcode, jenkins, ipa, xcodebuild

I'm busy working on a Jenkins build that will be building iOS applications. I have managed to create an archive successfully with this command:

```
xcodebuild archive -archivePath build/app.xcarchive
```

Now I'm trying to export that archive **with specifying the output file name**, but can't get this to work.In the example below I want an output file called app.ipa, but all I get is a folder called app.ipa with an ipa file inside name .ipa

```
xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportPath build/app.ipa -archivePath build/app.xcarchive/ -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist

Outputs a file /build/app.ipa/<projectname>.ipa
```

Apples documentation for XCodeBuild says that you can specify the output path including file name:

> -exportPath destinationpath
>              Specifies the destination for the exported product, including the name of the exported file.

https://web.archive.org/web/20170620204608/https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

The reason for this is that I would like to keep the build generic so that any project I send through it will result in an app.ipa without me needing to keep track of project names and different output files etc.

Comment: What is `xcrun xcodebuild`. I never saw something like that before.

Comment: "xcrun  provides  a means to locate or invoke developer tools from the command-line, without requiring users to modify Makefiles or otherwise take inconvenient measures  to  support  multiple  Xcode  tool chains."

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html

Comment: Yes, earlier without -exportOptionsPlist, the same command create the specified file, now after 8.3, its making a folder and inside that folder the .ipa is. Is there any workaround except using mv?

Answer (score 7):

This is filed as a bug in open radar: ["xcodebuild exportArchive -exportPath" does not write what it's documented to write](http://www.openradar.me/22890779)

Answer (score 4):

For XCode 11 and earlier:

**ArchiveAction** tag in .xcscheme file can have attribute **customArchiveName** which can be set to anything you like.

```
   <ArchiveAction
      buildConfiguration = "AdHoc_Example"
      customArchiveName = "app"
      revealArchiveInOrganizer = "YES">
   </ArchiveAction>
</Scheme>
```

This will give you `app.ipa` always when you export the archive through `-exportOptionsPlist`.

Comment: In XCode 12 it doesn't seem to work anymore. Wander if this is a bug or a feature :)

Comment: @Sasho `The “.ipa” file name is now sourced from the targets Info.plist file under the CFBundleName` https://www.wundermanthompson.com/insight/xcodebuild-exportarchive-changes-in-xcode12

Answer (score 3):

If you do a `xcodebuild --help` it says:

```
-exportPath PATH specifies the destination for the product exported from an archive
```

hmmm.

To do a workaround you can rename your file afterwards.

```
mv "oldname" "newname"
```

Comment: Hi, I would have liked to accomplish this without knowing what the "oldname" is. I want to repurpose this same build script for multiple projects and wont know what the output file name is.

Comment: So did apple get rid of the ability to specify a filename for the .ipa file?  Seems weird they let you specify it for the .xcarchive but not the resulting .ipa.

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit your Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>app</string>
```

Will give ipa.app

If you omit it, it will have the name of your `.xcarchive` file (Scheme name by default)

cf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908397