# xcodebuild exportArcive- How to customize the default IPA file name while exporting from command line?

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xcode7.3

I am using `xcodebuild` command line tool to create an archive and then export as IPA file, for my iOS project.

By default, while using `xcodebuild -exportArchive`, it creates the IPA file which has the **same label as the `scheme` selected for building**.

Is there anyway to change the output IPA file name while using `xcodebuild -exportArchive` from command line?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19696992/1457385

Comment: What I was able to find out is that *ArchiveAction* tag in .xcscheme file can have attribute *customArchiveName* which can be set to anything you like. However, I prefer to avoid this and omit this attr, so that resulting exported IPA is called exactly as the Scheme by which it is built. Then I just `mv` its default name to whatever I need by my CI build script.

Comment: @RAM237 can you share script and procedure to build ipa with custom name

Answer (score 5):

Change the `PRODUCT_NAME` in your target's Build Settings.

The parameter that sets your IPA name is actually `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME`, which is by default empty and thus defaults to your `PRODUCT_NAME`.

Answer (score 4):

Another way if that's not working is to set the customArchiveName (see this answer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/43809933

Answer (score 0):

set the info.plist -> Bundle name to $(PRODUCT_NAME)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.