# How can I create a shortcut to archive in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.1

I have to create many Xcode archive to upload IPA on HockeApp and iTunes Store.

Whenever I have to do it, I have to choose device as 'Generic iOS device' and the item `Archive` from `Product` Menu of Xxode.

Is there a way in Xcode to create a shortcut button or extension which can create an archive for me?

Comment: You should write a script that does it for each archive you need to build.  Use the xcode command line tools.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line

Comment: Thanks , but I am looking for a button here.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply make a key binding to the Archive option.

Go to **Xcode/Preferences/Key Bindings** and search for Archive to modify its shortcut.

[image: Key Bindings]

Comment: I can see the key bindings but unable to change it.

Comment: Double-click on the Key section of a key binding and press the key combination that you want to use.

Comment: Doesn't works for me. I remember I used it earlier and it worked but now it isnt working. Not sure what needs to be changed