# Can I build an IPA with an i386 + x86_64 architecture?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I've been asked to provide an IPA with an i386 + x86_64 architecture for a QA team.
From what I can see, this architecture is only available on the iPhone simulator where the option to build an IPA is greyed out, and the iPhone platform configurations support ARM architecture only.

Can anyone please advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: IPA is not an iOS app, IPA is a ZIP container, containing the code built using the parameters supplied to the compiler. If you change the IPA extension to ZIP, you can inspect the contents.

Comment: @matt, the iOS simulators have i386 + x86_64 listed as an architecture option. If it's not possible I need to respond to the QA team saying so, but that's what they're asking for.

Comment: Hey @user2078938, First of all if you provide them the IPA file of your project, it will only run in IPhone or IPad so do to that you give them this link also http://www.diawi.com. But you need to upload the zip file of your project remember zip file of only .app by building the project in selecting the option Generic iOS Device then build the project and make zip of the .app and upload to diawi and share with QA team for testing.

Answer (score 3):

This **may** be possible, but don't expect it to be easy, so your milage may vary.

You can use the `xcodebuild` command from the command line to build the .app file in the required architecture (or alternatively, when you run the app on the simulator, go to the DerivedData folder for your project and you should find the .app file in there somewhere)

You can then use the following command to archive it into an IPA:

`/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${RELEASE_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa" --sign "${DEVELOPER_NAME}" --embed "${PROVISONING_PROFILE}"`

Check out [This StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line) and [this blog post](https://blog.octo.com/en/automating-over-the-air-deployment-for-iphone/)

Comment: Will Jones, he wants for different archi. which is not supported on iOS

Comment: @HarjotSingh, The iOS Simulator is i386 + x86-64 architecture, as per their question.

Comment: How testers will get ios simulator? They have real devices i think.

Comment: Anyone with a Mac can get the Simulator. This discussion is off topic and isn't helpful to the OP.